# Why does glGetIntegerv for GL_NUM_SHADER_BINARY_FORMATS generate GL_INVALID_ENUM?

Tags: android, enums, android-ndk, sdl, opengl-es-2.0

I am using the official Android port of SDL 1.3, and using it to set up the GLES2 renderer.  It works for most devices, but for one user, it is not working.  Log output shows the following error:

```
error  of type 0x500 glGetIntegerv
```

I looked up 0x500, and it refers to GL_INVALID_ENUM.  I've tracked down where the problem occurs to the following code inside the SDL library: (the full source is quite large and I cut out logging and basic error-checking lines, so let me know if I haven't included enough information here)

```
glGetIntegerv( GL_NUM_SHADER_BINARY_FORMATS, &nFormats );
glGetBooleanv( GL_SHADER_COMPILER, &hasCompiler );
if( hasCompiler )
    ++nFormats;
rdata->shader_formats = (GLenum *) SDL_calloc( nFormats, sizeof( GLenum ) );
rdata->shader_format_count = nFormats;
glGetIntegerv( GL_SHADER_BINARY_FORMATS, (GLint *) rdata->shader_formats );
```

Immediately after the last line (the glGetIntegerv for GL_SHADER_BINARY_FORMATS), glGetError() returns GL_INVALID_ENUM.

Comment: This is mainly a guess, but in this case, against the specification if I read it correctly, this might mean device does not support any binary shader formats (and 'assumes' no one would call GL_SHADER_BINARY_FORMATS if GL_NUM_SHADER_BINARY_FORMATS == 0).

Comment: Thanks, that seems reasonable.  I'll see if zero was the return value, and see if skipping this part will cause any other problems later on.

Comment: It turns out GL_NUM_SHADER_BINARY_FORMATS == 1 (nFormats becomes 2, in the above code example, because "hasCompiler" is true).  However, glGetIntegerv for GL_SHADER_BINARY_FORMATS is still causing the GL_INVALID_ENUM.  I've worked around the problem by telling the code there are zero shader binary formats when the problem occurs, but I would still like to figure out why this is happening.  Thanks very much for the tip, though - it probably would have taken me longer to come up with a workaround if you hadn't suggested it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility extension is not properly supported on your system.

By GL_INVALID_ENUM it means that it does not know the GL_NUM_SHADER_BINARY_FORMATS and GL_SHADER_BINARY_FORMATS enums, which are a part of the said extension.

In contrast, GL_SHADER_COMPILER was recognized, which is strange.

You can try using GL_ARB_get_program_binary and using these two instead:

```
#define GL_NUM_PROGRAM_BINARY_FORMATS                                0x87fe
#define GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_FORMATS                                    0x87ff
```

Note that these are different from:

```
#define GL_SHADER_BINARY_FORMATS                                     0x8df8
#define GL_NUM_SHADER_BINARY_FORMATS                                 0x8df9
```

But they should pretty much do the same.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!  Is there a link to an example that does this?  I apologize, I am new to GL and some of your answer went over my head (specifically, how to "use GL_ARB_get_program_binary", where to put those #defines, and if anything else in the code from my first post would need to change.  Also, would these changes have any effect on systems that do properly support "the GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility extension"? (the app that is using this is distributed on the Android Market to many devices, most of which do not have the aforementioned problem)

Comment: Ok, gotchya now (sorry about that).  I'll give it a shot to see if it works (and if using it has any negative affect on other devices).